# Different route handlers unable to access req.session.isSupervisor value in react-express-mysql website

Tags: express, session, session-cookies

I am working on an auditing website with two user roles - supervisors and team members. The user logs in to the system using his unique user ID and password. Whether the user is a supervisor or not is determined by his unique User ID. I am using express as the service-side language and react as the client-side language.

### index.js ->  (the main entry point of my backend)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sessionMiddleware = require('./middlewares/sessionMiddleware/SessionMiddleware');
const Users = require("./routes/users/Users");

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

/* Use session middleware */
app.use(sessionMiddleware);

app.use("/users", Users);

app.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```

### database.js -> (contains MySQL database connections)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors(), express.json());
require('dotenv/config');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 10,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
});

async function checkDatabaseConnection() 
{
  try 
  {
    const connection = await pool.promise().getConnection();
    console.log('Connected to MySQL database successfully');
    connection.release();
  } 
  catch (err) 
  {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL database:', err);
  }
}
checkDatabaseConnection();

module.exports = pool;
```

### SessionMiddleware.js -> (contains session and stores session in MySQL DB)

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mysqlStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const pool = require("../../config/database");
const { GenerateSessionSecretKey } = require('../../utils/sessionSecretKeyGenerator/GenerateSessionSecretKey');

require("dotenv").config();

const Options = {
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    createDatabaseTable: true
};

const sessionSecretKey = GenerateSessionSecretKey(); 
const SessionMiddleware = express();
const sessionStore = new mysqlStore(Options, pool);

SessionMiddleware.use(session({
    secret: sessionSecretKey,
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { 
        cookie: { 
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        SameSite: "none",
        httpOnly: true
      },
    },
    store: sessionStore,
}));

module.exports = SessionMiddleware;
```

### [Main Error Here] User.js -> (contains User authentication and fetch-data routes)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require("../../config/database");

router.post('/sign-in', (req, res) => {
    const { userID, password } = req.body;
  
    const handleSupervisorLogin = (supervisorResults) => {
      req.session.isSupervisor = true;
      res.status(200).json({ isSupervisor: true, userID: supervisorResults[0].ID });
    };
  
    const handleMemberLogin = (memberResults) => {
      req.session.isSupervisor = false;
      res.status(200).json({ userID: memberResults[0].ID });
    };
  
    const handleError = (err, message) => {
      console.error('Error executing MySQL query:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ message });
    };
  
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) {
        return handleError(err, 'Internal server error');
      }
  
      const sql = `SELECT ID, Password FROM supervisors WHERE ID = ? AND Password = ?`;
  
      connection.query(sql, [userID, password], (err, supervisorResults) => {
        if (err) 
        {
          return handleError(err, 'Internal server error');
        }
  
        if (supervisorResults.length > 0) 
        {
          return handleSupervisorLogin(supervisorResults);
        }
  
        const memberSql = `SELECT ID, Password from team_members WHERE ID = ? AND Password = ?`;
        connection.query(memberSql, [userID, password], (err, memberResults) => {
          connection.release();
          if (err) 
          {
            return handleError(err, 'Internal server error');
          }
  
          if (memberResults.length > 0) 
          {
            return handleMemberLogin(memberResults);
          }
  
          console.log("User not found");
          return res.status(500).json({ message: 'User not found' });
        });
      });
    });
  });


  router.get('/:userID', (req, res) => {
    const { userID } = req.params; 
    const isSupervisor = req.session.isSupervisor; //Shows undefined
  
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) 
      {
        console.error('Error getting MySQL connection:', err);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
      }
  
      const sql = isSupervisor ? 'CALL FetchSupervisorData(?)' : 'CALL FetchMemberData(?)';
  
      connection.query(sql, [userID], (err, userResults) => {
        connection.release();
        if (err) 
        {
          console.error('Error executing MySQL query:', err);
          return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
        }
        res.status(200).json({ userData: userResults[0] });
      });
    });
  });
  
  module.exports = router;
```

I cannot access req.session.isSupervisor from users/:userID.

I console logged the req.session from users/sign-in and it shows isSupervisor = true, but this value seems missing when I console logged req.session from users/:userID.

I am at a loss here. Can anyone me please? Any help is appreciated!